# Play a local video with YouTube Player

Tags: video, youtube, flash

Is this possible? Can I play a local video with a YouTube player? Where can I download the code?

Thanks

**EDITED:**
What I really want is a player similar to YouTube's, It needs to look the same, so I can play the videos of my web that are going to be locally stored.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Michael I'm not sure what he ment, maybe he wants a flash video player similar to YouTube's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't expand the question. (and maybe even so...)

The answer is NO, no way.

Sorry!

**EDIT:**

If you actually ment have a video player LIKE Youtube's thats a whole different story.

If you cant find a Flash video player similar to Youtube's you may want to consider a tool like [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/index.html). Or any other out there.

> The most popular one <sup>don't know
>   how I forgot</sup> is [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/).
>   See a demo [here](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-player-now/).
>  Thanks
>   [@Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187954/michael-robinson) for the comment.

You could build your own Flash video player:

http://www.communitymx.com/abstract.cfm?cid=4E1D8
http://www.thetechlabs.com/tech-tutorials/audionvideo/how-to-build-a-as3-videoplayer/

<sup>(haven't tried any of these!)</sup>

But that's not an easy task (I understand).

You've tagged the OP javascript I took it out because I though that is not what you ment but if you did, you should try [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/) an "HTML5" video player.

Good luck! please comment or edit you question if you want more in detail answers (from me or anybody else).

Comment: @Michael thanks! don't know how I overlook that. edited and added to the answer!

Answer (score 0):

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/local-video-player-in-bro/gooogiookckojjoinofnjfogcfocfkbn?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

Use this Chrome extension to play local videos on Chrome.