# Is it possible to play a video file (eg .avi) using youtube player?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Can I use youtube player to play my own videos?

Say I have a localhost running and I have some video files stored and I have a html code that has Youtube player's code and I can specify something like

```
<src="localhost/videos/cat.avi">
```

And it plays cat.avi on my browser just like youtube player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - you can't play local videos using youtube player.

If you want to play them you'll need to upload them to youtube.com.

Check out [Play a local video with YouTube Player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856725/play-a-local-video-with-youtube-player)